Modelling loops/recursion in nuSMV
I am experimenting with nuSMV, and think I have made some conceptual error that I cannot figure out. I was interested in trying to model loop-like behaviour, modelling a loop by conditionally updating variables based on an exit condition. However this doesn't work because nuXmv appears to try and generate states that shouldn't be valid, and so overflows integer bounds. I am assuming this is because I'm making a mistake.
To try and make this easier to follow, I have tried to simplify what I was doing to a model that is trying to compute a triangular number in a variable "sum". The loop is bounded in the range 0..5 using a variable called "counter" so my exit condition which guards the transitions is "counter < 5".
The error I get is that at Line 30 (the close of the case...esac for the update to "sum"), cannot assign value 12 to variable sum.
I note that I don't get an error for the update to 'counter' so I'm wondering if as nuXmv tries to build the model, it assumes counter can remain static (because the 'sum' part of the model cannot yet see the transitions in counter), hence I'm getting a value that shouldn't be feasible in the calculation I am modelling.
What am I doing wrong and what have I misunderstood about how SMV models work?  Is there a way of fixing it?
Note that I have tried expanding the range of sum arbitrarily high, and hit a similar error. I have tried a similar model without the overarching state machine, with no difference in output (but I've included it here because I think it explains what I'm trying to do in each segment).  I'm also hoping that if this can be solved, I could do it for more general exit conditions than a bounded loop.
My simplified model is:
MODULE main
VAR
    state : {START, CHECK_CONDITION, EXECUTE_BODY, TERMINATE};
    counter : 0..5;
    sum : 0..10;

ASSIGN
    init(state) := START;
    init(counter) := 0;
    init(sum) := 0;

    next(state) :=
        case
            state = START : CHECK_CONDITION;
            state = CHECK_CONDITION & counter < 5 : EXECUTE_BODY;
            state = CHECK_CONDITION & counter >= 5 : TERMINATE;
            state = EXECUTE_BODY : CHECK_CONDITION;
            state = TERMINATE : TERMINATE;
        esac;

    next(counter) :=
        case
            state = EXECUTE_BODY & counter < 5 : counter + 1;
            TRUE : counter;
        esac;

    next(sum) :=
        case
            state = EXECUTE_BODY & counter < 5 : sum + counter;
            TRUE : sum;
        esac;

-- Specification to ensure that when the loop terminates, the counter is 5
SPEC AG (state = TERMINATE -> counter = 5)

-- Specification to ensure that when the loop terminates, the sum is 10 (sum of first 4 numbers: 0+1+2+3+4=10)
SPEC AG (state = TERMINATE -> sum = 10)

-- Specification to ensure the loop body is executed exactly five times
SPEC AG (state = EXECUTE_BODY -> (counter >= 0 & counter < 5))

